# mysql show Count of rows from other table in each row

Tags: mysql, select, count

```
select `personal`.`id` AS `id`,
`personal`.`name` AS `name`,
(select count(visit.id) 
      from visit,personal 
        where visit.user_id=personal.id) as count 
from personal;
```

im trying to get all users and the counts of visits they did.

the result i get is all users but the count column contain same value (not specific to that row id).

what am i doing wrong here ? how to tell mysql to user this row id ?

is compound select optimum way to do it or is there a better way ?

Comment: Try below answer, that has all the possibilities

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.id, p.name, COUNT(v.user_id)
FROM    personal p
LEFT JOIN
        visit v
ON      v.user_id = p.id
GROUP BY
        p.id
```

You may also use subselect of course (for instance if you have `ANSI` `GROUP BY` compatibility on):

```
SELECT  p.id, p.name,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    visit v
        WHERE   v.user_id = p.id
        )
FROM    personal p
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I am not wrong ...second query also needs `group by`. otherwise it will give multiple records from first table.

Comment: @Dharmeshpatel: both queries will return same resultsets.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 SELECT
Pe.id AS id,Pe.name AS name,COUNT(v.user_id) number_visit
FROM personal Pe
LEFT JOIN visit Vi
   ON Vi.user_id= Pe.id
GROUP BY Pe.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
   p.id AS `id`,
   p.name AS `name`, 
   IFNULL(v.TheCount, 0) TheCount
from personal p
LEFT JOIN
( 
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) TheCount
  FROM visits v
  GROUP BY user_id
) v ON v.user_id = p.Id;
```

Comment: This will not return persons with zero visits.

Comment: @Quassnoi Sorry, it should be fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That will work with `LEFT JOIN` tables `personal` with `visit`.

```
SELECT 
    Pe.id AS id, Pe.name AS name, COUNT(v.user_id) number_visit
FROM
    personal Pe
LEFT JOIN
    visit Vi ON Vi.user_id = Pe.id
GROUP BY Pe.id
```

If you want only user which are having atleast visit count 1, do `RIGHT JOIN` OR `HAVING` in `Group By`

```
SELECT 
    Pe.id AS id, Pe.name AS name, COUNT(v.user_id) number_visit
FROM
    personal Pe
RIGHT JOIN
    visit Vi ON Vi.user_id = Pe.id
GROUP BY Pe.id
```

**OR**

```
SELECT 
    Pe.id AS id, Pe.name AS name, COUNT(v.user_id) number_visit
FROM
    personal Pe
LEFT JOIN
    visit Vi ON Vi.user_id = Pe.id
GROUP BY Pe.id HAVING number_visit > 1
```